# What is the Right-Hand Limit as x approaches 0 of the nth root?

Tags: calculus, limits

A textbook says that

"One-sided limits are useful in taking limits of functions involving radicals. For instance, if is an even integer, then

[image]

I need help proving this, Ive gotten as far as this

[image]

Thank You.

The textbook is Calculus Larsons, 10th Edition page 72

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt[x]{n}$ or $\sqrt[n]{x}$? (Both seem to appear in your question.)

Comment: I mean the second

Comment: In the statement of your question, you mention $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ but in your attempt you have $\lim_{x\to 0^-}$. Which one should it be? I suppose $+$.

Comment: sorry about that yes it should be 0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the limit is from the positive side of $x$, we write

\begin{align}
0 < x < \delta & \longrightarrow 0 < x < \varepsilon^n \\
               & \longrightarrow 0 < \sqrt[n]{x} < \sqrt[n]{\varepsilon^n} \\
               & \longrightarrow 0 < \sqrt[n]{x} < \varepsilon
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay to me, but it would help to clean it up. Write: Given $\epsilon > 0 \: \exists \: \delta = \epsilon^n$  such that for $0<x < \delta \implies \sqrt[n]{x} - 0 < \sqrt[n]{\epsilon^n} = \epsilon$.